# Google Cloud Storage pricing for Archive Objects

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to use this new GCP feature: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/storage-data-transfer/archive-storage-class-for-coldest-data-now-available

But I'm not able to find the minimal retention, and the cost for retrieval. 
Can anyone help me to undertand pricing for this service?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check this link https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing in this document google describes pricing for each of storage class(Standard Storage, Nearline Storage, Coldline Storage, Archive Storage)

Comment: I only see Standard, Nearline and Coldline, not Archive.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like the spanish version is outdated.

Answer (score 0):

[here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing) is the pricing Table for further reference.

As of now the costs for Archive are:

- Class A operations (per 10,000 operations):  $0.50
- Class B operations (per 10,000 operations):  $0.50
- Free operations:                              free
- Data retrival per GB:                        $0.05

The minimum storage duration is of 365 days